# Output window doesn't show Pascal (Lazarus compiler)

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I was trying to make a little test program to count how many times letter 'a' appears in an text without using string type:

```
program PascalTest;
uses WinCrt;
var 
 a:integer;
 ch:char;
begin
 a:=0;
 writeln('Input text: ');
 read(ch);
 while ch <>'.' do // '.' marking the end of text ("eoln" could've been used instead)//
  begin
   case ch of
   'A','a':a:=a+1;
   end;
   read(ch);
  end;
writeln(a);
readln;
readln; //forcing output window to stay open//
end.
```

I noticed that if I dont add another 'readln' statement at the end , the output window will not show results (it will flash in an instant if u will).This is happening only with this program.All the other ones require only one 'readln' so the window can stay open. Can somebody explain to me why is another 'readln' statement needed in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `readln` ends the `while` loop. Note that you can enter many '.' without loop exit. Further note the `writeln(a)` is delayed until you press `<Enter>`. The second `readln` allows you to view the output.

Make a test: Uncomment both `readln` and see if you can end the program by entering a '.'.

Comment: I see , so this is a required procedure for these types of programs (mainly programs working with character inputs)? And I uncommented both readln statements.The result is same as with only one readln.

Comment: Really? Can you leave the loop without enter? If you use CRT as Marco suggested, you can replace the `read(ch)` with `ch := readkey;` and get immediate response to '.', but you have to echo the input.

Comment: Thanks for explaining CRT.  And ,I hope I'm not misunderstanding anything here, but to be precise, with one readln and without both of readln statements , when I input e.g. "aaa." and hit <ENTER> , the result is the same:Output window doesn't show. I hope this answers can I leave loop without <enter>.

Comment: Huh? You wrote: `when I input e.g. "aaa." and hit <ENTER>`, but then you obviously pressed `<ENTER>`. If you start your program from the GUI the console window will close (you say `Output window doesn't show`) after pressing `<ENTER>` if there is no or one `readln`. The first `readln` consumes the `<ENTER>` after "aaa.", you must press two `<ENTER>` if there are two `readln´. Another test: open a stand-alone console window in your executable directory (under Windows execute CMD and CD into the directory) and start your program, you will see the output and the window **will not close**.

Comment: Yes I understand that the window will not close , but only if I put two readln. And yes, I will need to hit <enter> two times for window to close. After executing:One <enter> for inputting text and to get a result, and second <enter> to close window.Did you mean that?There is no way that window will stay open without two readln, right?

Comment: Normally not. Depending on the OS there might be an window option 'Do not close' or similar. Another method is to use crt.delay for a short time before the window closes.

Comment: Delay function is the only way to avoid readln that I could find.I'm wondering if my OS or machine is causing this or it is just "the way it is" . Anyway thank you very much for your time and answers.

Answer (score 0):

WinCrt is a consoleless CRT to use in combination with unit GRAPH.

Use unit Crt for normal console output.

Comment: I dont understand what does the Crt unit has to do with my question. In this case I have same results with or without Crt unit.

Comment: I mostly reacted to the "no output windows show". IOW I thought the console window didn't open.